# why can't I create my private variable where I declare it?

Tags: ruby

Consider the following code

```
class CheckOut 
    @rules
    @total = 0
    @basket = Hash.new 

    def initialize(rules, discounts)
        @total=0
                #if i use the line below everything is ok.
        #@basket = Hash.new
        @rules = rules
    end

     def scan sku
          price = @rules[sku]
          if @basket.has_key?(sku) #I get NoMethodError: undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass
             @basket[sku] += 1
          else 
              @basket[sku] = 1
          end
          @total += price
     end    

     def total
        @total
     end
end
```

If I run the code as is I get a noMethodError on has_key? but if I create the Hash in initialize everything works. Why can't I create the Hash at the declaration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you define an instance variable in the class body, it's a *class instance variable* defined on `CheckOut`, which is an instance of `Class`, and doesn't exist in an instance of `CheckOut`. Instead you need to define the instance variables in your `initialize` as you've found (since `initialize` runs in the context of the new `CheckOut` instance):

```
class CheckOut
  def initialize(rules, discounts)
    @total = 0
    @basket = Hash.new
    @rules = rules
  end
  ...
end
```

Here's a quick example illustrating this further:

```
class Foo
  @bar = "class bar!"
  @baz = "class baz!"
  def initialize
    @bar = "instance bar!"
  end
end

Foo.instance_variable_get(:@bar)  #=> "class bar!"
Foo.new.instance_variable_get(:@bar)  #=> "instance bar!"

Foo.instance_variable_get(:@baz)  #=> "class baz!"
Foo.new.instance_variable_get(:@baz)  #=> nil
```

This also shows that *all* instance variables default to `nil`, even if they've never been referenced before. This is why your error is a `NoMethodError for nil:NilClass` and not a `NameError`.